# parent proxy not working in 3proxy

Tags: proxy

i was install latest version of 3proxy on ubuntu 16.04 from source with this config:

```
nscache 65536
nserver 8.8.8.8
nserver 8.8.4.4

config /conf/3proxy.cfg
monitor /conf/3proxy.cfg

log /logs/3proxy-%y%m%d.log D
rotate 60
counter /count/3proxy.3cf

users $/conf/passwd

include /conf/counters
include /conf/bandlimiters

#auth strong
auth none
#deny * * 127.0.0.1
allow *
parent 1000 http IP PORT user pass
proxy -n
socks
flush
allow admin

admin -p8080
```

but parent proxy is not working!
when i install older versions of 3 proxy , it's working correctly.

please help:/

thanks

Comment: You should probably research this over on Unix& LinuxSE https://unix.stackexchange.com/